# Unable to run AngryBots.unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to run the Unity example Angry Bots but I am getting the following error:

Assets/Standard assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(32,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'wantedRotationAngle'.

I am using Unity Version 3.5.0f5

I have tried redownloading/importing the project from the Asset Store but I am still getting the error.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade to Unity 4.0.1 fixed this issue.